# why was this off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309426/non-community-wiki-answers-and-grammar?noredirect=1#comment266564_309426) on the stack overflow meta page regarding what I found to be confusing grammar in some stack overflow phrases, and suggested that it be changed.

The pushback where I posted the original suggestion implied that I was wrong, or at least that the change wasn't worth being made.  I was pretty sure I was right, but I'm no expert, so I posted a [question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/non-community-wiki-answers-or-non-community-wiki-answers?noredirect=1#comment28809_7280) on English Language & Usage.  It looks to me to be a pretty clear question about English grammar rules.  That question was migrated to the English Language & Usage meta.  Why?

Comment: I can't answer your question, because I wasn't one of the ones who migrated it, but I agree that it shouldn't have been migrated to ELU Meta.

Comment: I was one who voted to migrate to meta. I think that was a mistake, because it really is about hyphenation and not about changing the message in SE (which is what I first read i as). However it is closable then as a duplicate of the linked ones in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your post belongs on main and not Meta. I'm not sure why it migrated. The delay was because I wasn't sure how to send it back without deleting it, but I think I figured that out. Please comment on this answer if you discover something wrong about the migration.